# Consulta COUNT() não funciona

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

O objetivo da consulta é listar, num período definido pelo usuário, todos os estados e o seu número total de cotações independente se for zero. Os clientes precisam estar ativos (status 30) e possuírem nº de id da cidade mencionada.

A tabela `vangebot` possui as cotações, com nº id do endereço do cliente e data de emissão:

```
angebotid | eingabeDatum | adressebestellerid - nº do endereço
201970110 | 01/06/2019   | 26087
201970111 | 25/05/2018   | 15305
201970112 | 23/06/2016   | 18447
```

A tabela `gpartner` possui informações sobre o cliente:

```
partnerid | partnername | status
24270     | Oliveira    | 30
24669     | Medsíntese  | 30
24665     | Assessoria  | 30
21122     | X           | 30
```

A tabela `gadresse` possui o endereço vinculado ao cliente na tabela `gpartner`, com o número da cidade:

```
adresseid | partnerid | adresseName  | postfachplz - nº da cidade
26087     | 24270     | R. Alviverde | 193
15305     | 24669     | R. 358       | 2043
18447     | 24665     | Av. Leopoldo | 1890
14151     | 21122     | R. Barroca   | 30
```

A tabela `its_microRegion` possui a cidade e a microrregião vinculados de acordo com o endereço mencionado na tabela `gadresse`:

```
id   | city           | uf - nº da uf
193  | Porto Alegre   | 23
2043 | Belo Horizonte | 17
1890 | Rio de Janeiro | 19
30   | Alecrim        | 12
```

A tabela `its_Region` possui o nome do estado, vinculado com a tabela `its_microRegion`:

```
id | uf | regionName
23 | RS | Rio Grande do Sul
17 | MG | Minas Gerais
19 | RJ | Rio de Janeiro
12 | GO | Goiás
```

Elaborei a seguinte consulta:

```
select its_Region.uf, its_Region.regionName, count(vangebot.angebotid) as qtdCotacoes from vangebot
left join gpartner on vangebot.kundeid = gpartner.partnerid
left join gadresse on gadresse.adresseid = vangebot.adressebestellerid
left join its_microRegion on gadresse.postfachplz = its_microRegion.id
inner join its_Region on its_microRegion.uf = its_Region.id
where vangebot.eingabeDatum between '2016-01-01' and '2019-06-02'
and gpartner.status = 30 and gadresse.postfachPlz <> ''
group by its_Region.uf order by qtdCotacoes desc;
```

### Resultado:

```
uf | regionName        | qtdCotacoes
RS | Rio Grande do Sul | 1
MG | Minas Gerais      | 1
RJ | Rio de Janeiro    | 1
```

### O que deveria mostrar:

```
uf | regionName        | qtdCotacoes
RS | Rio Grande do Sul | 1
MG | Minas Gerais      | 1
RJ | Rio de Janeiro    | 1
GO | Goiás             | 0
```

Porém, o resultado apresentado só menciona os estados que possuem cotações vinculadas e os demais não. O que eu devo fazer?

### Código DB Fiddle:

[Consulta COUNT](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hge64ssD3W9x5Xx4ZrJX6B/9)

Comment: Não criei as tabelas para testar de fato, mas provavelmente você tenha que usar o left_join ou right_join ao invés de inner_join. De uma pesquisada sobre isso

Comment: Consegue fazer um [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com) para facilitar acharmos o problema?

Comment: @Sorack, acabei de inserir o fiddle. Consegue dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter o resultado desejado você deve usar na cláusula `FROM` a tabela que contém os dados principais, que neste caso são os Estados. Portanto mude a ordem dos seus `JOINs` para conseguir o restante dos dados a partir disso. É importante usar o `LEFT` para remover a obrigatoriedade. No `WHERE` verifique os campos apenas se o `id` da tabela em questão for `NULL`, garantindo que mesmo o Estado que não tenha dados relacionados seja mostrado:

```
SELECT its_Region.uf,
       its_Region.regionName,
       COUNT(vangebot.angebotid) AS qtdCotacoes
  FROM its_Region
  LEFT JOIN its_microRegion ON its_microRegion.uf = its_Region.id
  LEFT JOIN gadresse ON gadresse.postfachplz = its_microRegion.id
  LEFT JOIN vangebot ON gadresse.adresseid = vangebot.adressebestellerid
  LEFT JOIN gpartner ON vangebot.kundeid = gpartner.partnerid
 WHERE (vangebot.angebotid IS NULL OR vangebot.eingabeDatum BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2019-06-02')
   AND (gpartner.partnerid IS NULL OR gpartner.status = 30)
   AND COALESCE(gadresse.postfachPlz, '') <> ''
 GROUP BY its_Region.uf
 ORDER BY qtdCotacoes DESC
```

Que resultará em:

```
| uf  | regionName        | qtdCotacoes |
| --- | ----------------- | ----------- |
| RJ  | Rio de Janeiro    | 1           |
| RS  | Rio Grande do Sul | 1           |
| MG  | Minas Gerais      | 1           |
| GO  | Goiás             | 0           |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hge64ssD3W9x5Xx4ZrJX6B/11).

Comment: Realmente funciona no fiddle, porém ao aplicar no meu DB o resultado demora pois as tabelas possuem quase 20mil registros. Não tenho certeza se isso implica na consulta ou não. Acrescentei mais alguns detalhes de que a consulta deve proporcionar, acredito que estamos chegando lá.

Comment: @GabrielMalthaLuiz mas na pergunta você não citou nada de performance e sim de assertividade, que está completamente coberto pela resposta.

Comment: Concordo plenamente, esqueci deste detalhe. O que mais posso te informar para que possamos resolver? Posso elaborar um diagrama entidade relacionamento das tabelas que mencionei.

Comment: @GabrielMalthaLuiz nada, não faz parte da pergunta. Você pode fazer uma outra pergunta sobre performance.

Comment: ok, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer o select com `join` apenas entre as tabelas `its_region` e `its_microRegion` para obter todos os estados. As demais tabelas com `left join`:

```
SELECT ITR.uf, ITR.regionName, COUNT(VAN.kundeid) AS qtdCotacoes
from its_Region ITR
inner join its_microRegion IMR
on IMR.uf = ITR.id
LEFT join gadresse GA on GA.postfachplz = IMR.id
LEFT join gpartner GP on GP.partnerid = GA.partnerid
LEFT JOIN vangebot VAN ON GP.partnerid = VAN.kundeid 
where (van.angebotid IS NULL OR van.eingabeDatum BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2019-06-02') AND 
gp.partnerid IS NULL OR gp.status = 30 AND 
ga.postfachPlz <> ''
 group by ITR.uf, ITR.regionName, VAN.kundeid
 order by qtdCotacoes desc;
```

OU com uma subquery:

```
SELECT ITR.uf, ITR.regionName, 
(SELECT COUNT(VAN.kundeid) 
 FROM vangebot AS VAN 
 INNER JOIN gpartner AS GP on VAN.kundeid = GP.partnerid
INNER JOIN gadresse AS GA ON GP.partnerid = GA.partnerid 
WHERE VAN.eingabedatum between '2016-01-01' and '2019-06-02' AND
    GP.status = 30 and GA.postfachPlz <> '' AND GA.postfachplz = IMR.id
) AS qtdCotacoes
FROM its_Region AS ITR
INNER JOIN its_microRegion AS IMR
ON IMR.uf = ITR.id
ORDER BY qtdCotacoes DESC;
```

Comment: entendi tua construção, porém ainda sim obtive o mesmo resultado. Os estados que não tem cotação continuam não aparecendo.

Comment: É por causa das condições na cláusulas where. Você tem que colocar: where VAN.angebotid IS NULL OR 
      (VAN.eingabeDatum between '2019-06-01' and GETDATE() AND gp.status = 30) ... Aí vai trazer todos os Estados que não tem cotações.

Comment: talvez seja isso, eu estabeleci a consulta e não obtive resultado. Será que há uma possibilidade de fazer uma subquery? Se sim, como ficaria?

Comment: Eu vou fazer a consulta aqui e já te passo.

Comment: @GabrielMalthaLuiz fiz a consulta com a subquery. Para cada Região, vai fazer uma consulta para ver se existem Cotações. Coloquei na minha resposta.

Comment: Nenhuma das `queries` executa. Aconselho que você teste suas soluções no `Fiddle` fornecido pelo OP

Comment: @Sorack é verdade, desculpem minha falta de atenção. Agora as consultas estão executando. Criei numa base direto no MySQL.